# Implementation of while loop in bubble sort?

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I want to write a bubble sort program in Ruby. Please do not suggest a new way of doing this without first pointing out the bug in my code. I can look up the answer to a Ruby bubble sort method, but I can't figure out why my code doesn't work.

I'm using a `while` loop, however, my method doesn't seem to loop continuously until it passes entirely once without making a swap. Am I not using the `while` loop correctly?

Here's my script:

```
def bubblesort(array)
      i = 0 
      swapped = true
      lenght = array.length-1
      while swapped do
          swapped = false
          while i <lenght
              n = i +1
              if array[i] > array[n]
              dummy = array[i]
              array[i]= array[n]
              array[n] = dummy  
              swapped = true

              end
             i+=1
          end

      end
      return array
end
```

Comment: You have "while swapped do", so why not "while i < lenght do", do you only need to use "do" once or is this an error?

Comment: I'd rename the `lenght` variable to `length` ;)

Comment: Hi Ali. If one of the answers helped you solve your problem, you should mark it as the accepted answer and/or upvote it. Please refer to [faq] for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `i` variable doesn't get reset to `0` when you go to your second iteration within `while swapped do`.

Doing it that way, the second loop isn't entered more then once.

This would work:

```
def bubblesort(array)
      swapped = true
      lenght = array.length-1
      while swapped do
          i = 0
          swapped = false
          while i <lenght
              n = i +1
              if array[i] > array[n]
                  dummy = array[i]
                  array[i]= array[n]
                  array[n] = dummy  
                  swapped = true
              end
             i+=1
          end
      end
      return array
end
```

Comment: I tried a quick example [here](http://codepad.org/DG4CNVPT).
Seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is for 11 elements. you can change the size to any number

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

void swap(int *,int *);
void printArr(int *,int Siz=11);
int main(){

int a[]={1,4,15,10,12,6,3,2,8,5,7};
//int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,5,7,8,10,11,9};

int len=11,i=0,j=0,temp=0;
bool swapped=false;
    while(i<len){

        swapped=false;j=0;
        while(j<len-1){
            if(a[j]>a[j+1]){
                swap(&a[j],&a[j+1]);
                swapped=true;
            }
            cout<<"loop : "<<i<<" "<<a[j]<<" "<<a[j+1]<<endl;
            j+=1;

        }
        i+=1; len-=1; //as the largest value has already moved to last location. need no further comparison
        if(!swapped) break;
    }
    printArr(a);
    system("pause");
}

void swap(int *a,int *b){
    int t=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=t;

}

void printArr(int *a,int Siz){
    for(int i=0; i<Siz; i++) cout<<a[i]<<" "; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

http://codepad.org/8BsoiWQo

```
def bubblesort(array)
      i = 0 
      swapped = true
      length = array.length
      while i < length-1 and swapped do # also check for end of array
          swapped = false
          n = i +1  # second loop variable 'n' should be initialized here
          while n < length
              if array[i] > array[n]
                  dummy = array[i]
                  array[i]= array[n]
                  array[n] = dummy  
                  swapped = true
              end
             n += 1 # 'n' should be incremented here...
          end
          i += 1 # and 'i' here
      end
      return array
end
```

I'm not a rubby programmer, but I tried C# equivalent of this code, and it worked fine.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't have a Ruby IDE (also know nothing about ruby!), so I converted your program to C#, corrected it, and converted it back to Ruby. Sadly the second conversion has some mistakes! I corrected them. Also tested the code in an online Ruby IDE : [http://codepad.org/8BsoiWQo](http://codepad.org/8BsoiWQo)

Comment: You can swap like this: `array[i], [array[n] = array[n], array[i]`. (http://codepad.org/RdR8SgLi)

Answer (score 0):

As steven suggested. The problem is with your i=0.  It should be moved into the first while loop so it can reset.

To save from all the confusion with the 2nd while loop.

(array.length-1).times do |i|
 code.....
end

the above works great.  Resets i each time.